# Learning java for android: do docs at android site also cover native java libs

Tags: java, android

I am learning java for first time. I have found it's very similar to haxe and flash as3.

However, i am also learning android. And in that i have learned that android overwrites many native java libs to improve speed or something.

Now this creates a problem...i am learning java separately because tutorials about android assume you know java. And this means continuing this path will result in me learning it one way and then the right way. Wasting brain...

So can someone clear confusion. Are all libs covered at http://developer.android.com/reference/packages.html ...or java in android also support more native libs. How would i know which libs are added/overwritten by android into native libs..

also can you suggest what libs/methods i should know to be not stuck at every step.

By libs i mean packages and methods.

Comment: For most of them, Android uses standard Java (1.6, or SDK 6). However, some Java packages are not included (e.g. `java.awt`, `javax.swing`) since Android implements alternatives that are more efficient for itself. Android also have some more APIs that are not available in Java SE. So, the best thing I can recommend, is to check both Java and Android docs when in doubt.

Comment: thanks...i have one problem..i can't find the correct reference for the java i am using at oracle site there seems to be many variations of java. can you give me the link

Comment: this is off topic (java, android, documentation)?

Comment: Here is the link to [Java SE 6 docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/). Recently, Android supports some of Java 7 features, but for now, you can just ignore that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look here for Android Tutorials and docs, and use the reference you've already found.
http://developer.android.com/training/index.html

You may find it goes smoother if you finish learning Java first. The GUI is completely different from Java, but works well. Some Java Classes from older Android API levels are missing some methods, but that is all documented in the developer reference.

Comment: it's just missing l, it was html...link is not working

Answer (score 1):

Learn Java, skip the graphical / GUI part and you're fine, I think. You can use almost everything from plain java. There are just minor differences like using threads. But that's nothing to worry about.